# Updating SQL Server database without duplicates

Tags: c#, sql-server

I wrote this program couple of months back that delimits these large `.CSV` files and uploads them into a SQL Server database. Since the `.CSV` file was just basically being appended each time with new data I just had it set up so that each time user uploads data it would delete everything from the table and upload the newly appended data like so:

```
myConnection.Open();
string sql = @"DELETE FROM TestTable;";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, myConnection);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
myConnection.Close();
```

Now I have to set it up to upload the data without deleting previous entries to the table but the catch is I can't have duplicate data. Luckily the `.CSV` file comes with unique identifier for each row which I use as primary key but I'm having trouble coming up with algorithm to do this. Is there perhaps something similar to `DELETE` syntax above that I can use with SQL Server to only update unique data? I'm asking you guys since I'm not the biggest expert when it comes to SQL Server.

I have couple of different classes and background worker so didn't want to past all of the code since its a lot, but if you guys need any specifics let me know.

EDIT

There is a example here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y06xa2h1(v=vs.80).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

of what I'm pretty sure I need to do, but only thing I'm confused about is what is dataSet1 and where is it coming from? I'm just using connection string to open connection to the SQL Server database and then use `SqlDataAdapter` to perform functions like inserts and stuff.

If anyone has any clarification on this that would be of great help.

Thanks

Comment: if you have unique id you can insert if id not found otherwise ignore or update existing data...

Comment: what is the syntax for not found?

Comment: SQL Server (Microsoft)

Comment: You say "*Now I have to set it up to upload the data without deleting previous entries to the table..*".  The question is, *why do you now have to upload without deleting the previous data?*  The answer to this question should determine what the best approach is.

Answer (score 1):

A *cheapo* way to achieve this would be to create a unique index on your unique identifying column in SQL Server, and tell it to just simply ignore any duplicates.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UIX_YourIndexNameHere
ON dbo.YourTableNameHere(YourUniqueColumnNameHere)
WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON);
```

This means:

- SQL Server will only allow unique values in this column - no duplicates
- if any duplicates are being inserted, they will be tossed out without raising any error ("silently ignored", so to speak)

This also means:

- possible duplicates will just be ignored - the existing row for that unique ID will remain *as is* (no updates)
- new rows are being inserted

If you need to update pre-existing rows with their ID, I would recommend to do this:

- bulk load the .CSV into a temporary staging table
- use the `MERGE` command (hoping that you're using SQL Server **2008** or newer!) to update the real table from the staging table; this allow easily inserting new rows and **updating** (instead of ignoring) pre-existing rows